# OpenFileDialog multiselect targetpath from textbox

Tags: c#, multi-select, openfiledialog

Hy everyone,

I would like to copy multiple selected files with openfiledialog to a folder which is defined as `@"C:\TestFolder\"+ textBox1.Text`. My problem is that somehow the program writes the textBox content in the file name too.

Please find below my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog od = new OpenFileDialog();
    od.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    od.Multiselect = true;
    if (od.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string targetPath = @"C:\TestFolder\"+ textBox1.Text;
        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, textBox1.Text);

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        } 
        foreach (string fileName in od.FileNames)
        {            
            System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, path + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
        } 
    }
}
```

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Try this one:

```
 string Main_dir = @"C:\TestFolder\";
 string Sub_dir = textBox1.Text + @"\";
 string targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Main_dir, Sub_dir);
      {
           if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
      {
           System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
      }
           foreach (string fileName in od.FileNames)

           System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, targetPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName), true);
      }
```

Backslash is missing

> - @"\"

Answer (score 0):

These things are equivalent.

```
string targetPath = @"C:\TestFolder\"+ textBox1.Text;
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, textBox1.Text);
```

I would drop the first one for the `Path.Combine` call as it is portable and robust when it comes to the separators.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do not know why but if I remove the first or the second line my code stop working properly. It copies the file only in the main folder C:\TestFolder\ than create an empty folder with the name written in the textbox.

Comment: what is textBox1 used for?

Comment: Its an ID number for documents. I need it for file structure.